# Facebook Graph API - Returning Liked Page Name

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any reliable way to extract the user liked page names and number of followers (only the name and followers and not any other data) by using the Graph API.

This is my code so far in C#.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
public interface IFacebookService
{
    Task<Account> GetAccountAsync(string accessToken);
    Task PostOnWallAsync(string accessToken, string message);
}

public class FacebookService : IFacebookService
{
    private readonly IFacebookClient _facebookClient;

    public FacebookService(IFacebookClient facebookClient)
    {
        _facebookClient = facebookClient;
    }

    public async Task<Account> GetAccountAsync(string accessToken)
    {
        var result = await _facebookClient.GetAsync<dynamic>(
            accessToken, "me", "fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,age_range,birthday,gender,locale,location,website,likes,feed");

        if (result == null)
        {
            return new Account();
        }

        var account = new Account
        {
            Id = result.id,
            Email = result.email,
            Name = result.name,
            UserName = result.username,
            FirstName = result.first_name,
            LastName = result.last_name,
            Gender = result.gender,
            Birthday = result.birthday,
            Locale = result.locale,
            Location = result.location.name,
            Website = result.website,
            Likes = result.likes.data,
            Feed = result.feed.data
        };

        return account;
    }

    public async Task PostOnWallAsync(string accessToken, string message)
        => await _facebookClient.PostAsync(accessToken, "me/feed", new {message});
}  
}
```

The output for liked pages is something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Richard Dawkins",
  "id": "1376933789198289",
  "created_time": "2018-01-04T08:21:24+0000"
},
```

As you can see, it gives data that is unnecessary, like the ID and created_time. All I am interested in is the name and number of followers so I can sort the pages alphabetically and by number of likes. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to access followers of a user profile. If you need additional fields for the liked Pages:

```
/me?fields=likes{name,fan_count}
```

or:

```
/me/likes?fields=name,fan_count
```

There is no alphabetical sorting or sorting by likes though, you would have to do that on your own after getting the data. Also, you cannot get the number of people who "follow" Pages, only the number of likes.

Check out the API docs to find out which fields you can get: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Comment: I meant the number of followers that a liked user page has. For example, if I like 2 pages on Facebook, I want to extract the number of followers (or even number of likes, if it's not possible to return the number of followers) and sort them by that in my application.

Comment: you cannot access followers at all, not the count and not the users. make sure you understand the difference between followers and fans. followers are for user profiles, fans are for pages. if you mean that "following" flag on pages, it´s impossible to get a count for those. you can only get the like count - with the "fan_count" field.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for the confusion. This is what I was looking for.